# why does ImageMagick resizes all images regardless the resize limit?

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to apply a resize limit for ImageMagick but it does't seem to work as supposed in the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink). I am using **ImageMagick 6.9.2-3-portable-Q16-x86** in Windows 7.

```
convert input.jpg -resize 1920x1080^> -quality 92 output.jpg
```

When the input file is larger that 1920x1080, it gets resized nicely.

When the input file is smaller, e.g. 1024x768, although I would expect it to be untouched, it does get saved with the same resolution (1024x768) and different file size, depending on the quality set.

Shouldn't parameter `-resize 1920x1080^>` force ImageMagick to skip that file?

If not, then how can we skip those files that are smaller than the resize limit set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to work like that... your command says *"Take `input.jpg` and resize it if larger than 1920x1080, then change its quality and save it."*

You can run something like this before you execute your command to see if it needs resizing - it will output `1` or `0` depending on whether the image needs resizing or not:

```
identify -format "%[fx:(w>1920)||(h>1080)?1:0]" 1921x1080.jpg
1

identify -format "%[fx:(w>1920)||(h>1080)?1:0]" 1920x1080.jpg
0
```

If you want to put that `0` or `1` in a variable, you do something like:

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in ( `identify -format "%[fx:(w>1920)||(h>1080)?1:0]" 1921x1080.jpg` ) do set resize=%i
```

and double up the percent signs in a `.BAT` file.